# function of a senquence ( Sn ) without recursive

Tags: c

How can i do this senquence without a recursive function
[image]

the mean of ( ^ ) is && in this question

in rec i wrote but without i cant get it right

```
Sn(int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            return ex4_rec(n - 1) + ex4_rec(n - 2) + ex4_rec(n - 3);
        else
            return ex4_rec(n - 1) - ex4_rec(n - 3);
}
```

Comment: please post code than attach images.

Comment: i tried and it didnt let me post for some reason

Comment: There are no `^` or `&&` in the question

Comment: @IrAM There are `∧` in the question, you don't see them?

Comment: Interestingly this results in two mingled Fibonacci sequences :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int n) {
    long long s0 = 1, s1 = 1, s2 = 1;
    printf("1, 1, 1");
    for (int k = 3; k < n; k++) {
        long long next;
        if (k % 2 == 0) {
            next = s2 + s1 + s0;
        } else {
            next = s2 - s0;
        }
        printf(", %lld", next);
        s0 = s1;
        s1 = s2;
        s2 = next;
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    foo(100);
}
```

Edited: moved most functionality out of `main()`

Answer (score 1):

```
int s[n+3];
s[0] = s[1] = s[2] = 1;
 for(int i=3;i<=n;i++){
     if(i%2==0) s[i] = s[i-1]+s[i-2]+s[i-3];
     else if(i%2==1) s[i] = s[i-1] - s[i-3];
 }
You can use array like this.
```

Comment: if `n=1` you access out of bound `s[0] = s[1] = s[2] = 1;`

Comment: yes, those corner cases op should handle. I am not here to spoon feed

Comment: sure ... for n = 10e19?

Comment: note that `if (condition) {} else if (!condition) {}` is redundant

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to save the previous three results, so you need a 3-element array initialized with the first three values in the sequence:

```
int S[3] = {1, 1, 1};
```

So if `n` is less than 3 (0, 1, or 2), you just return the value in that index:

```
if ( n < 3 )
  return S[n];
```

If `n` is 3 or greater, then you loop from 3 up to `n`, pushing each result onto the end of the array (and discarding the oldest result):

```
for ( int i = 3; i <= n; i++ )
{
  if ( i % 2 ) // i is odd
    val = S[2] - S[0];
  else
    val = S[2] + S[1] + S[0]

  // throw away the oldest value, shift the previous two values
  // down 1, store the most recent value:

  S[0] = S[1];
  S[1] = S[2];
  S[2] = val;
}
```

When the loop exits, `S[2]` contains the result for `n`, so just return that:

```
return S[2];
```